# how to get last sunday of march month using spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to implement the logic for daylight saving. for that i need to get the last sunday of march every year. How to get it using spark sql?

I should be getting 1 AM of last sunday every year march. i tried different methods but nothing is working.

Comment: What do you mean by "implement the logic for daylight saving"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think daylight saving matters here. You can find the last Sunday of March using finding the dayofweek of Apr/1 and subtract it from the Apr/1.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(data = [
    [2021],
    [2022],
    [2023]
], ['year'])

df = (df.withColumn('apr1', F.to_date(F.concat_ws('-', F.col('year'), F.lit('04-01'))))
      .withColumn('dow', F.dayofweek('apr1'))
      .withColumn('last_sun', F.to_timestamp(F.concat(F.expr('date_sub(apr1, dow-1)'), F.lit(' 01:00:00')))))
```

Result

```
+----+----------+---+-------------------+
|year|      apr1|dow|           last_sun|
+----+----------+---+-------------------+
|2021|2021-04-01|  5|2021-03-28 01:00:00|
|2022|2022-04-01|  6|2022-03-27 01:00:00|
|2023|2023-04-01|  7|2023-03-26 01:00:00|
+----+----------+---+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

- Get the last day of March (`last_day` column)
- Converts it to day of week **(1=Monday,...,7=Sunday)** (`last_day_number` column)
- If it's 7 then the last day of march is a Sunday
- Otherwise substract the value of day of week to get back to the last Sunday which will be the last one in March

Code:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [(2019,), (2020,), (2021,), (2022,), (2023,)], ["year_col"]
    )

    df = (
        df.withColumn(
            "last_day", last_day(concat(col("year_col"), lit("-03-01")))
        )
        .withColumn(
            "last_day_number", date_format("last_day", "u") # 7 = Sunday
        )
        .withColumn(
            "last_sunday_of_march",
            when(
                col("last_day_number") == lit(7), col("last_day") # if last day of march is sunday, then it is the last sunday of march
            ).otherwise(
                expr("date_sub(last_day, last_day_number)") # else, subtract the number of days from the last day of march to get the last sunday of march
            ),
        )
    ).select("year_col", "last_sunday_of_march")
```

Result:

```
   year_col last_sunday_of_march
      2019           2019-03-31
      2020           2020-03-29
      2021           2021-03-28
      2022           2022-03-27
      2023           2023-03-26
```